# Alterar a forma de apresentação dos itens selecionados no select

Tags: html, css

Tenho o `select` com campo de pesquisa e com todos os valores selecionados de padrão, como mostro:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".meuselect").select2();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 4%;">
<form action="post"> 
   <select style="width:300px;" data-placeholder="Selecione Utente" class="form-control meuselect" name="Utente[]" id="Utente" multiple>
  <option value="UM" selected="selected">UM</option>
  <option value="Dois" selected="selected">Dois</option>
    <option value="Três" selected="selected">Três</option>
    <option value="Quatro" selected="selected">Quatro</option>
    <option value="Cinco" selected="selected">Cinco</option>
    <option value="Seis" selected="selected">Seis</option>
    <option value="Sete" selected="selected">Sete</option>
    <option value="Oito" selected="selected">Oito</option>
    <option value="Nove" selected="selected">Nove</option>
    <option value="Dez" selected="selected">Dez</option>
    <option value="Onze" selected="selected">Onze</option>
    <option value="Doze" selected="selected">Doze</option>
    <option value="Treze" selected="selected">Treze</option>
    </select>
</form>
</div>
```

O resultado dentro da combobox fica desta forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pretendia que ficasse tudo igual como na imagem, mas em vez de aparecer o **X** aparecessem checkboxes marcadas, como por exemplo nesta imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse tipo de componente é construido no HTML como um select padrão, mas quando é renderizado no DOM o JS transforma ele na verdade em uma `UL/LI` e coloca nos elementos `classes`, `ids`, e `aria atributes`.

O "option" fica com a classe `select2-selection__choice__remove`, então eu usei esse seletor para pegar o item e coloquei nele um pseudo elemento `::after` para fazer o `✔` no lugar do `X`

**OBS:** `Checkbox` não vai funcionar, pq quando vc desmarcar o item vai sumir da tela, então não faz sentido tem um `checkbox` sendo que vc não vai poder marcar/desmarcar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
.select2-selection__choice__remove {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
.select2-selection__choice__remove::after {
  font-size: 12px;
  content: "✔";
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<div style="margin-top: 4%;">
  <form action="post">
    <select style="width:300px;" data-placeholder="Selecione Utente" class="form-control meuselect" name="Utente[]" id="Utente" multiple>
      <option value="UM" selected="selected">UM</option>
      <option value="Dois" selected="selected">Dois</option>
      <option value="Três" selected="selected">Três</option>
      <option value="Quatro" selected="selected">Quatro</option>
      <option value="Cinco" selected="selected">Cinco</option>
      <option value="Seis" selected="selected">Seis</option>
      <option value="Sete" selected="selected">Sete</option>
      <option value="Oito" selected="selected">Oito</option>
      <option value="Nove" selected="selected">Nove</option>
      <option value="Dez" selected="selected">Dez</option>
      <option value="Onze" selected="selected">Onze</option>
      <option value="Doze" selected="selected">Doze</option>
      <option value="Treze" selected="selected">Treze</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".meuselect").select2();
  });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: mas a ideia era retirar o "X" e ficar uma checkbox como coloquei na segunda imagem, é possível?

Comment: @Bruno Cara, foi mal, entendi errado, dei uma Editada na resposta. De qq forma, checkbox não faz sentido, já que uma vez que vc clica nele ele some da tela, então não faz sentido usa-lo, já que não da para mara-lo e desmarca-lo, já que no primeiro clique ele já sumiria

Comment: mas veja este exemplo, aparece assim: [primeira forma de visualização do utilizador](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FgM0.jpg) e assim Utilizador aprofundar visualização](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09jVJ.jpg), era assim que pretendia. Mas desta forma, a possibilidade de pesquisa (possibilidade de escrever o nome) como no exemplo acima, deixamos de ter. É possível fazer desta forma?

Comment: @Bruno acredito que não, ai  vc teria que além de mudar o  CSS como eu mudei vc teria que mudar também o JavaScript do plugin, ele teria que ao criar a listagem ul/li, também criar um checkbox, e ainda "lincar" esse checkbox com as opções da lista, acredito ser algo bem complexo de ser feito, sugiro que vc procure outro componente de select caso vc queira uma opção desse tipo... ou então vc vai ter que manjar MUITO de JS para fazer isso que vc  quer

Comment: e existirá um outro componente de select que vá de encontro com o que procuro?

Comment: @Bruno acho que vc não foi muito claro na sua pergunta, por isso creio não ter entendido direito o que vc queria... de qq forma esse link deve te ajudar, acho que é o que vc  está procurando https://codepen.io/faur/pen/vWVPGE

Comment: ´@hugocsl sim, é mesmo isso que estou a procurar